Cannot turn off following and get weird message popup
Until now I could unfollow questions only from my profile (some time ago. Previosly could do it on the question also). But today instead of removing the unchecked question (by clicking the x top right corner) this message popup appears and the question is not unfollowed and removed from the list. I tried to signed out and in again and delete the cookies no avail.

User has already voted this way. Undo the vote, or change the vote to continue.

This same message appears if I want to undelete it directly on the question site.
The example site link is here
Another issue that in the title it is mentioned that it was edited 2 days ago but the edit is not signed at the bottom of the sheet. What does then it mean?


There's an MSE version of this too

@Robert Thanks I use only SO and the Help redirect me to this site. Should I delete this question here?

As far as I'm aware it's fine to have the question in both places.

This might be connected to other things. I've just encountered this, but what prompted me to notice it was that I got an inbox message about a comment on a question I was supposedly following... But the only thing I ever did was downvote that question (it was off-topic, so damn if I want to follow something like that).

Fixed: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/401395/362795 . I unfollowed all my followed posts.

From Ham Vocke over on Meta Stack Exchange:

Ouch. This one's a big one, huh?
I woke up this morning and saw a round of bug reports around retracting votes. I could track the issue down to a faulty change we had pushed out to production last Friday. This change touched our vote validation logic, a very central piece of our Q&A code, and it looks like we introduced a bug that went by unnoticed.
Not going to sugar-coat it: We really should've caught this one before getting it out to production, and we didn't. The fact that this bug persisted over the weekend makes this even more jarring. I'm sorry that this happened and apologize that we didn't catch it in time. I'll make sure we look into what happened here and come up with ways to do better next time.
The issue should be resolved now.

